# Accurately retrieving xy location of agent in p5.js

Tags: javascript, p5.js

In [this codepen](https://codepen.io/jalapic/full/JENERj/) I am trying to change the color of cells (called patches) of a grid as an agent moves over it.  The example has only two agents (I use var turtle using [Netlogo](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/models/Paths) terms in the pen).

At each step of draw, I try to calculate the number of agents on each cell/patch of the grid:

```
// this is how much to increase popularity by if an agent is on the patch
var popularityPerStep = 20; 

//I calculate the x/y position of all agents:
turtlesXpos = turtles.map(f => f.pos.x); 
turtlesYpos = turtles.map(f => f.pos.y);
```

I then use this function to try and count how many on each cell/patch and update the popularity accordingly:

```
function Patch(i, j) {

  this.i = i;
  this.j = j;
  this.popularity = 0; // at setup popularity is 0.
  this.totalTurtles = 0;

// countTurtles on each patch
 this.findTurtles = function() {

this.totalTurtles = 0;
for(var ii=0; ii<turtleTotal; ii++){
  if(turtlesXpos[ii] > this.i * w &&
     turtlesXpos[ii] < w + (this.i * w) &&
     turtlesYpos[ii] > this.j * h &&
     turtlesYpos[ii] < (this.j * h) + h
    )
  this.totalTurtles++;
};
}; 


// Update popularity
this.updatePopularity = function() {
this.popularity += popularityPerStep*this.totalTurtles
};


// Display patch
  this.show = function() {

  rect(this.i * w, this.j * h, w, h); // dimensions of patch

// color rectangle based on poularity
      if (this.popularity >= 1) {
        fill("gray"); //pcolor gray
      } else {
        fill("#90EE90"); //pcolor green
      }
    };
```

It seems to count the agents/turtles on each cell at each tick correctly, but the coloring of cells is off.  As seen in the pen, it is recoloring the cells/patches that are one row below the location of agents.   This seems like it should be a simple math error, but perhaps I've done something wrong in `p5.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to narrow your problem down to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You can hardcode a single "patch" in the middle of the screen and check against the mouse position or something.

Without an MCVE it's pretty hard to debug all that code, but the problem seems to be at least partially caused by this line:

```
if(turtlesXpos[ii] > this.i * w &&
 turtlesXpos[ii] < w + (this.i * w) &&
 turtlesYpos[ii] > this.j * h &&
 turtlesYpos[ii] < (this.j * h) + h
)
```

I thought maybe you had an off-by-one error here, so I tried subtracting `1` from your `this.j` variable (which should really be named something like `this.cellY` for readability).

```
if(turtlesXpos[ii] > this.i * w &&
 turtlesXpos[ii] < w + (this.i * w) &&
 turtlesYpos[ii] > (this.j-1) * h &&
 turtlesYpos[ii] < ((this.j-1) * h) + h
)
```

I figured this would fix the cell offset, but to my surprise it actually made it worse! Now the cells that were 2 spaces below the agents were changing for some reason.

So I instead changed it to **add** `1` to the `this.j` variable:

```
if(turtlesXpos[ii] > this.i * w &&
 turtlesXpos[ii] < w + (this.i * w) &&
 turtlesYpos[ii] > (this.j+1) * h &&
 turtlesYpos[ii] < ((this.j+1) * h) + h
)
```

And this seems to fix your problem.

However, I wouldn't just take this code and keep on trucking if I were you. This is a symptom of something going wrong in your code. You need to track down where this offset is coming from and fix that. Are you maybe drawing the cells from the bottom-left corner instead of the top-left corner?

If you still can't get it figured out, **please** try to narrow your code down to an MCVE instead of posting your entire project.